# Extracting text from OCR image file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract few fields from OCR image. I am using pytesseract to read OCR image file and this is working as expected.

**Code :**

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import re

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract- 
OCR\tesseract.exe"

value = Image.open("ocr.JPG")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(value)
print(text)
```

**Output :**

```
ALS 1 Emergency Base Rate
Y A0427 RE ABC
Anbulance Mileage Charge

Y A0425 RE ABC
Disposable Supplies
Y A0398 RH ABC

184800230, x
```

Next, I have to extract A0427 and A0425 from the text.. but the problem is I am not loop through the whole line.. it's taking one character at a time and that's why my regular expression isn't working..

**Code:**

```
for line in text :
    print(line)
    x= re.findall(r'^A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', text)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Get rid of start `^` anchor from your regex. That is stopping the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of that for loop also, use only

```
x= re.findall(r'A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', text)
```

without any loop. ('remove ^ too')

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a string, default behavior for Python when looping over a string using a `for`-loop is to loop through the characters (as a string is basically a list of characters).

To loop through the lines, first split the text into lines using `text.splitlines()`:

```
for line in text.splitlines() :
    print(line)
    x= re.findall(r'^A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', text)
    print(x)
```

EDIT: Or use Patels answer to skip the loop all together :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your regex is start anchor `^` which expects your matching text `A0425` should start from the very start of line and that is indeed not the case as you have `Y` and space before it. So just remove `^` from your regex and then you should be getting all expected strings. Also, you can change four of this `[0-9]` to write as `[0-9]{4}` and your shortened regex becomes,

```
A[0-9]{4}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OiVzhS/1)**

You need to modify your current code like this,

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import re

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract- 
OCR\tesseract.exe"

value = Image.open("ocr.JPG")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(value)

print(re.findall(r'A[0-9]{4}', text))
```

This should prints all your matches without needing to loop individually into lines,

```
['A0427', 'A0425', 'A0398']
```